# Как правильно говорить: автобусы ходят или ездят?

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: автобусы *ходят* или *ездят*?

Answer (score 3):

О направленном и систематическом движении автобуса по расписанию говорят "**ходит**", а люди на нём "ездят". Если речь о текущем моменте, то и автобус "едет", и люди "едут" на нём. В отдельных случаях автобус "ездит" - кругами, туда-сюда, ещё как-то странно:

"Вчера наш корпоративный автобус **ездил**  за город забрать сотрудников с базы отдыха".

Автобус ходящий по расписанию, может "подойти", а случайный может "подъехать" - без особой строгости в различиях.

Answer (score 1):

Как и весь прочий транспорт - едут, но если едут по маршруту, они, становясь рейсовыми, идут.

Answer (score 1):

Автобусы (троллейбусы, трамваи, автомобили, поезда) в большинстве случаев **ходят**, вне зависимости от того, по расписанию они или нет. И в нейтральном стиле следует говорить именно так. Можно, конечно, сказать "подъехал автобус" или даже подкатил, подлетел ("Трамваи оглушительно звенели, *подлетая* к площади", у Булгакова трамвай тоже "тотчас и *подлетел*").

Answer (score 1):

Автобус может даже тащиться, ковылять, шарахаться из стороны в сторону.  Мы просто привыкли отождествлять средство передвижения с нами самими, срослись и душой и телом.
вообще ездят на...,  а едет он.

Answer (score 1):

В споре о значении слов решающим аргументом всегда будет словарь. Например, Малый Академический словарь:

> ИДТИ, иду, идёшь... 1. Передвигаться, перемещаться в пространстве. а) Передвигаться,
> ступая ногами, делая шаги (о человеке и животном). [...] б) Двигаться в определенном
> направлении, по определенному маршруту: ехать, плыть, лететь (о средствах передвижения).
>
> ЕХАТЬ, еду, едешь... 1. Двигаться, перемещаться по суше или воде при помощи каких-л.
> средств передвижения. *Ехать верхом*.

Ожегов-Шведова:

> ЕХАТЬ, еду, едешь... [...] 2. (1 и 2 л. не употр.). О средствах передвижения: двигаться. *Едет автомобиль*.

Ну, и для полноты картины - Ушаков:

> ЕХАТЬ, еду, едешь... [...] || Двигаться, катиться (о самих средствах передвижения; разг.).

=====================

Таким образом, автобусы могут "ездить" по версии, например, Ожегова; а по версии, например, Ушакова - только в разговорном стиле (не литературно-нейтральном). **Идти** же (и **ходить**) поезда и автобусы могут по версии всех словарей, совершенно нейтрально (не разговорно).

Answer (score 0):

"shampar" на его:

"**Как и весь прочий транспорт - едут, но если едут по маршруту, они, становясь рейсовыми, идут.**"

=====================

По Вашей версии получается, что правильней говорить "По шоссе **ехали** машины", вместо "По шоссе шли машины"?

**Моя версия ответа: Уж такова особенность русского языка, что машины сами по себе идут, а не едут. Ехать Вы можете внутри транспорта, а вот сам транспорт идёт. И это не зависит от постоянного маршрута или же от чего-то ещё**

Comment: ну да,  не ногами же шли, а ехали. А по вашей версии они еще и топать должны?

ШАМПУР ....НА НЕГО НАСАЖИВАЮТ.

Comment: В моём ответе нет слов о правильности, о шоссе, о машинах. Не понял,  в свою очередь, почему вопросом отвечаете на вопрос.

Comment: Господин(жа) "**shampar**", я поздравляю Вас - Вы показали мастер-класс, умудрившись в двух предложениях, допустить 4,5 неадекватности:
1)**"В моём ответе нет слов о правильности"**
==============
 Милейший(ая) не надо искать идиотов в своих оппонентах. Вы помните какой вопрос был задан? Совершенно верно - "Как **правильно** говорить..." Не обязательно, чтоб в Вашем ответе было слово "правильность". Ваш ответ должен и подразумевает это, если Вы, конечно, не блаблакаете, а отвечаете по сути вопроса...

Comment: 2) "**Не понял, в свою очередь, почему вопросом отвечаете на вопрос**"
==============
а) Видите ли, есть общепринятые правила в риторике, и они, к счастью, не зависят от Ваших капризов, а потому не предусматривают какие-либо запреты облачать свой ответ в форму вопроса. Тем более с риторическим уклоном. Если это не так, то проясните мне, тупому нерусю, какими нормами предусмотрено Ваше утверждение.
б) Я не отвечал на Ваш вопрос, а напротив ставил перед Вами вопрос.

Comment: "ну да, не ногами же шли, а ехали. А по вашей версии они еще и топать должны?"
Господин "**petro**", Вы зря ёрничаете. Не надо ставить свои 2 копейки - лучше бы ответили по сути и аргументированно, если, конечно, Вам есть что сказать.
Как Вы думаете, когда объявляют "По второму пассажирскому пути будет проходить грузовой поезд, будьте осторожны!" то что этим подразумевают - поезд будет маршировать по второму пути, размахивая руками, или же...?
Испокон веков машины по шоссе шли, а не ехали. Ехать Вы можете внутри этой машины, а сами машины, уж извините, идут.

Comment: Испокон веков машины по шоссе шли, а не ехали. Ехать Вы можете внутри этой машины, а сами машины, уж извините, идут.

Вот и ответ готов. Только автору надо оформить эти строки как ответ, а не комментировать комментарии комментирующих. Смотрите на вопрос!

Comment: Я только что увидел данное Ваше сообщение. Прошу простить меня, как новичка, не имеющего должного опыта. Теперь, приняв к сведению Ваше замечание, а главное благодаря ему, буду знать как поступать в следующий раз.