# Расщепляет кого или что?

Tags: орфография, управление

Как правильно сказать:

"Препарат расщепляет паразиты" или "Препарат расщепляет паразитов"?

И почему?

Comment: @Юрий1982, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: под паразитами, здесь имеются ввиду глисты

Comment: а вы пробовали расщеплять глистов, топориком, например. :)
Там в минздраве русского не знают, так не уподобляйтесь фармакологам из миннздрава, они в инструкции не то что расщепляют, они еще и транквилизируют.
Гравицапой. Лишь бы препарат купили.

Comment: Petro. Мы здесь, что обсуждает, грамматику русского языка или свойства медицинских препаратов. Странно получается: препарат расщепляет паразитов, но препарат расщепляет глисты (не глистов же)

Answer (score 1):

Если паразиты-глисты,то это одушевлённое сущ.и корректно будет "Препарат расщепляет паразитов".

Сначала мне тоже, как и petro,фраза показалась странной, но оказалось, что на медицинских и ветеринарных сайтах и правда пишут о препаратах ( например, Вермокс и Декарис), которые  воздействуют на мышцы и нервные ганглии червей, парализуя их, в результате чего они теряют способность удерживаться в организме и расщепляются желудочным соком человека. А плоды дынного дерева содержат фермент — папаиназу, которая способна расщеплять белок гельминтов. Препараты этого растительного фермента с успехом применяются в медицине. Некоторые химические вещества (гексил- и гептилрезорцин) тоже способны повреждать кутикулу гельминта, а также проникать в его тело.

Кандидат ветеринарных наук, например,советует:

"Ещё важный момент - препараты против глистов парализуют и расщепляют на сегменты глистов, поэтому, чтобы предотвратить всасывание (т.е. переваривание) продуктов распада глистов из кишечника, собаке желательно через несколько часов после глистогонного дать ЭНТЕРОСГЕЛЬ. Он обволокёт содержимое кишечника и выведет наружу, не дав всосаться, и предотвратит интоксикацию организма".

Так что вполне корректная фраза,petro...

Comment: расщепить-многозначное слово, это не только расколоть на щепки, и раздробить,заставить распасться на части, но и (знач.3)"разложить на части путём физико-химической реакции". В этом значении и атом, его ядро  расщепляется, и белок гельминтов отдельными препаратами. Какие-то препараты только парализуют, а какие-то и расщепляют, вместе с  пищей, в желудке. Почему нет? Потому их и надо вывести, чтобы не всосались в стенки желудка.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения грамматики не верен ни один из вариантов, потому как, когда речь идёт об одушевлённых существительных (как в данном случае!), то их невозможно расщеплять ни физически, ни химически и ни семантически. Хотя, замечу, чудесный русский язык ещё и не то расщепляет (возможно удивитесь, но есть термины "расщепление голоса" и "расщепление горизонта").

Препарат может уничтожить, растворить и т.д., но "расщепить глистов" - никак. Таков 
 мой вариант ответа по существу формулировки самого вопроса.

P.S. Народ русский и не очень, вынужден писать тут, так как дважды обращался к администрации страницы, написав в "обратную связь", но что-то ответа так и не получил. Дело в том, что вопрос **"Как правильно говорить: автобусы ходят или ездят?"** ( [Как правильно говорить: автобусы ходят или ездят?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82) )

навели меня - не могу написать гордозвучащее (уважаемая "Виталина_ZX", сам вижу, что слитно:)! ) "вдохновили меня"! - на мысль написать небольшую заметку о чудесных, неподдающихся никакой логике, особенностях русского языка. Это может будет субъективной точкой зрения человека, с молоком матери не впитавшего русский, но тем не менее, считаю, что заметка должна быть интересной. В связи с чем у меня вопрос: "как связаться с администрацией страницы?". А ежели администрация сама увидит это обращение, то прошу ответить на вопрос: **Можно ли написать тут заметку? Если да, то каким образом?**

Comment: >Можно ли написать тут заметку? Если да, то каким образом?

@Наби Мусаибов, На сайте есть раздел [Исследования][http://russ.hashcode.ru/research/].

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Наби Мусаибов, с точки зрения грамматики верны оба варианта. А насколько эта информация соответствует действительности, это вопрос, да будет вам известно, не **ГРАММАТИКИ**.

Comment: Возможно Вы и правы, уважаемый "Серж". Давайте попробуем разобраться; у меня к Вам будет 2 вопроса:
1) Паразитов можно расщеплять?

Comment: Насчет паразитов не знаю. Не пробовал. Обращаться надо не ко мне, а к врачам. Уважаемый Наби, вопрос здесь не в том, можно или нельзя расщепить паразитов, а в каком падеже поставить  слово ''паразит''.  В винительном или родительном. С грамматической точки зрения, еще раз повторюсь, все в порядке. А вот насколько такая информация соответствует действительности  - не знаю. Но теоретически вполне такое возможно.

Comment: Любезнейший "Серж", я могу с Вами согласиться в том, что я не верно понял суть вопроса, так как, исходя из изначального условия "Как правильно сказать", перевёл всё в русло грамматики, тогда как человека в большей степени интересовало не это, а падеж (родительный или же винительный). Однако, когда Вы говорите, мол, с точки зрения грамматики всё тут корректно, то я задумываюсь над вопросом а правильно ли я вообще понимаю значение термина "грамматика"? В моём представлении это грамотно поставленная речь, безупречная во всех отношениях. Скажите, может я не верно понимаю смысл этого термина?

Comment: Наби, термин грамматика лишь отчасти включает в себя грамотную речь. Предложение может быть грамматически построено верно, без ошибок. Но в то же время стилистически не удачно. Грамотно поставленная речь должна отвечать всем языковым нормам. К грамматическим ошибкам обычно относят: 
*ошибки в образовании форм существительных: **"облеки", "англичаны", "два знамя", "на мосте", "Гринев жил недорослью", "Он не боялся опасностей и рисков", "Во дворе построили большую качель".**
* ошибки в образовании форм прилагательных: **"Один брат был богатей другого", "Эта книга более интереснее".**  и т.д.

Comment: Серж, у нас сейчас начинается голый и непродуктивный спор. Ваше "включает", даже завуалированное наречием "отчасти", несмотря на умалённость частицей "лишь", автоматически означает Ваше согласие с тем, что грамматика **"включает в себя грамотную речь"**. А с этой позиции предложение о расщеплении паразитов уже хворает, ввиду того, что паразиты не расщепляются. Уж так сложилось традиционно по-русски. А Ваше "Насчет паразитов не знаю...Обращаться надо не ко мне, а к врачам" ничуть не лучше: "Как можно сказать жене, что пирог у неё сгорел, если сам не имеешь кулинарного образования?!"

Comment: Уважаемый ВитаЛина и Серж, у меня вопрос один к вам: Куда делся раздел "Исследования", не скажете?

Answer (score 0):

*Столько шуму, а четкого ответа нет*.

Я рекомендую форму ***"Препарат расщепляет паразитов"***

"Паразит" - существительное, которое испытывает колебание в категории грамматической одушевленности, то есть может выступать и как одушевленное, и как неодушевленное существительное. При этом биологическая сущность паразита (растение это, животное,  насекомое, вирус или механизм-робот, а то и вовсе слово-паразит) играет в лучшем случае второстепенную роль. С этой точки зрения верны оба варианта. Однако в конструкциях, подобных рассматриваемой, да и вообще в медицинских текстах, "паразит" выступает как вполне живая субстанция и испытывает явное тяготение к одушевленности. Плюс к этому одушевленная форма часто менее двусмысленна (ср. *препараты расщепляют паразиты* - кто кого?). Поэтому я за вариант **"расщепляют паразитов"***.  Равно как и "глистов", "вирусов" и прочих *"колеблющихся сущностей"*.

> Существительное паразит является одушевленным, если употребляется по
> отношению к людям и животным (в широком смысле), и неодушевленным, если
> употребляется по отношению к растениям.

Если это просто утверждение без претензий на обобщение, то оно неверно.
Но если это у автора принцип такой (а похоже на то, если учесть настойчивость, с которой автор его продвигает), то это неверный подход в принципе. Он механически переносит закономерность (животные как правило одушевлены, растения - нет) на грамматику отдельного слова. Это в корне неверно. Возможно, что для каких-то слов подобное правило и имеет место (я таких не знаю), но в целом логика языка в подобных вопросах  базируется на совершенно других законах, в первую очередь - на исторических традициях и представлениях далеких предков-носителей, далеких от современной биологии. Классический пример - мертвец (или покойник) и труп. Первое одушевлено, второе - нет.

(+)
И совсем убийственный пример. Слово "организм". Оно может одинаково относиться и к животному, и к растительному организму. Ну не может же быть так, что в первом случае слово грамматически одушевлено, во втором - нет?! *"Изучать неизвестные организмы" (если растения) и "изучать неизвестных организмов" (если животных)?!*

Answer (score -1):

Существительное паразит является одушевленным, если употребляется по отношению к людям и животным (в широком смысле), и неодушевленным, если употребляется по отношению к растениям. Поэтому, если речь идет, например, о насекомых, правильно: **уничтожим любых паразитов. Но: прополоть грядки, уничтожить сорняки и паразиты**.

В примере, который вы приводите, возможны оба варианта, в зависимости от того, что подразумевается под  словом ''паразит''.

Вопрос о том, почему так, нужно искать в историческом развитии языка. Об этом можете, например, почитать здесь:
[О категории одушевленности/неодушевленности имен существительных](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=632.nNXkEZmLHDGtSozYQTlJLfWPnjxXmFDt0PIwBucXVFbSDUrSh02LeM5sCUG8EwtE_TWNKRDawuey1nSBWOisWWwtQSfWStPBGAqwx-wG5Gg.931bfa34e50b4551d6aeebca82df741ecabc5ce8&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsGes-COYeAtjuEaMUoBSHPfr4lKxvTHSyQ6n1j85zPHaXgiKUCn4cCONphBRLrC0MO2mZ1c_BuLjWF906OB6bYxd5ZgXNXU_E5OVQkOVte9siU9vnjh0OWIElMBxhyggTl0rEWpX4ytiVFQ7BG0ee50_6MaMiTbvKKnSgzlce9l_41UREzWWxP3741ISAxddVhAn_6Syt4Gkli0rrGcpTLiNoXjzJ-IuSuEJUPW_AmiQ&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxZ0ZqN0pxUlRoaXVsR2t0TF9YNjBKc0l4eHBKMzlFOFM1WEpPaU9QaHlYRlJHZ3Z6WlNia09aS053blRKUXFfdjE4SFVuSXJJYXBDaTFOeDc0MjQ5VkZURXZUSXo4b0dFTEFRb3c2NTZpMjdtUTJ2QnBOOXVVUQ&b64e=2&sign=efd6ab2a25f2b7d51617e6e9eca9e4ac&keyno=0&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3m4cVndcRMfNuguIXI6uHFKi9bhwWohZbJGZRgMkCk2-6JXtuLq_6PejmtiZNvu-HrS6YoPh28XEM8qUmaoqKRDxit7UX-mPbfkpbD7YVdKXhMQbDk3NBbfJLdcHwkowWTfn3yZzkA4MkChC7RkevI9SD46NaBsXZKNSY0Q_G8ZDYVVZmyb-yAetz7gvRebkNllACwlQUiOgl3slvKEvethkqq4RX4OkolT1O4bDR8eOju-afZxBw03mnRTjsM5l0d_SnIuINUalGqh23G754WBMKaCQACzK9m9UhJq9fXV7HNeejaYyCihqm3s12Ntf_EBo8jNtZ3jTKNyPUvUecZ9EJ3vEb42Cf9vBTEvN2G8HCrV9FulHfrUEmlgZqWb_eynPTS0XkrxaJOLxDo-_zlET_TmVOgS0GAIRoXkxfH1II1sv0k1N4a-W3FFRZxAGleapNuPPKf5JG6CwK0dKF6rVsWyNA3oKzaZjYj8GD7XZD9jCGQt-XwvHty1bxgdhSUKMdGVnZn3R3bs_6rgbzgPiEhLv67S3oNpo2YGWe7Fec8j9LkHHUIQpd6tTSk0w4SpJqfsoZrVwhyD4m5LODb6GSNNTzYS9grxNurQ_uvES5bYOzgIcA2EwVHptOZWyPgIO7yji8ddF_np67lr3LvYUxK-5wYnKQqckfWdzqIT52NLWU1JbFwMeetyfEJZQU9ZzK98C-EzIbj4VXFCIm0V9ag018jComGsOrxmaK2MQ-ItFFeM_CWmLVz4UTZRQiEZwkAfyHspVjaljFIGwoqVAVHCfxZsYiiEBgG_zXRvBIyUiHfUVDHjNfL75wQ0UIjTV_Sa2Dj0JD7BMfhhqjKtJWZTdhWgFIEuA2YwSLWPQXINQfHDQln5egpL3B-wUA3f3M7bHOqUme0k74dh55sL6-xCNRVpd8IearSLztmuxGKRhn8f9P3ZGjlyNEXPK6Vl3CMJKp_p2CLWG1G2vdA0gdoGtL5s_5eUN-ewfRPaLQvEGVoiRQGFAINpGheNd1aT5fPQxv3WfB6kPOQox-I8uqpnEz5HRuV640rHv8cif8dvycgQohOn5ecJ1_J-7g3FKepkkQAaEapneRTsiy8CcvjtPW7Ibjet3v4SoCv8F55GNZ8XQCUfCcHF62Jw6nf-xaVUgitNudb1A0twcPGvbPlwKk128_1FSLR8fZFoKN1KvgTiM9pYUlrfkDk2ErYQLImAjDeW3r_wFtdle8xXuJhx8SpV48Er9eI4zI28POt4Thg-9L3grLZ5XP3BjM-l3iDpNfrH1nyFfDsk1BVxDElPTjKwmwGSDOzJQCszmq12h9Yn_qLPBB7utKVlDpFR2iWijS93xMiIJKXdoKaeCVtBpuB5pZnD_krt142oiUygGBCkptwB4Ux_OPashZD9MsR3-57FKTigrCFx_gYzpYPrCnRgEaveVMKcSQx6njktADet5idckZ0MLiXwT9fbqVo4bJBB8tHTt_PmKMlfyK4xDFeL1TYYuA16QxoNDDcvKEaOp4BZn3Xh-Qvj2yfSHtApztCkaxFNAiWUskr9Bms28PYrWfWkegTfVucmt7We1owz7pxoEQOb8RJKfsyLSRHhAPAuO1XqBOmsMKRuDwLHleq-IT8&l10n=ru&cts=1426844024842&mc=3.7303377974034158)

Comment: странно, все время считал, что слова-паразиты, это отдельная категория, как и растения-паразиты, сиречь-сорняки. А уничтожать надо паразитирующих, как растения, так животных и насекомых, а не паразиты во множественном числе. Они паразиты множатся, но уничтожают паразитов, в том числе и растения-паразиты.

Comment: Петро, что вы хотите сказать? Излагайте свои мысли четче и обоснованно.